# How to figure out what the reason for submission failure of a Firefox crash report was?

Tags: ubuntu, firefox, crash

If Firefox crashes it displays a dialog asking for details about the crash and contact information and offers submission to the bug reporting system. These submission constantly fail for me, but the dialog only displays the pretty useless message *that* the submission failed. How can I figure out why this is the case?

In `about:crashes` I see the last successfully sent reports from 2016 which is before I experience daily crashes like in the last weeks. The list of unsent reports is empty.

I'm using Firefox 53.0.3 (64-Bit) on Ubuntu 17.04.

Comment: Good question. Might be one for the Mozilla forums.

Comment: @BoffinbraiN A question on a platform with meritocratic swarm intelligence control is so much more valuable than one in any forum, so as long as important parts of the internet aren't organizes in this way, Mozilla will have to serve the firefox tag here in order to profit from my good question.

Comment: All I'm saying is that you might get your answer faster if you go straight to the experts. If you get an answer from them, you can come back here and answer your own question, making things better for the rest of us.